# GHC StablePointer equality reasoning

Tags: haskell, ghc

I just learned about GHC's `StablePointer` feature, which is really cool, but I can't figure out why it has won't show things as equal. Here is my test case:

```
-- Example 1
import System.Mem.StableName

data Wrapper = Wrapper { getWrapper :: Int -> Bool }

myFunc :: Int -> Bool
myFunc = (> 4)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let m = Wrapper myFunc
  a <- makeStableName $ getWrapper m
  b <- makeStableName $ getWrapper m
  print (a `eqStableName` b)
  putStrLn "Done"
```

Pretty simple, but when I do `runhaskell` with GHC 7.8.4, I get a result of false. What about a simpler case? Let's try this:

```
-- Example 2
import System.Mem.StableName

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let m = (+2) :: Int -> Int
      n = m
  a <- makeStableName m
  b <- makeStableName n
  print (a `eqStableName` b)
  putStrLn "Done"
```

I still get a result of False. The only way I can get `eqStableName` to return `True` is when I call `makeStableName` on the same exact bound variable. Like this:

```
  -- in this example, r can be anything
  a <- makeStableName r
  b <- makeStableName r
  print (a `eqStableName` b)
```

But this is no longer helpful. I already know that every expression is equal to itself, so this doesn't give me any new information. My question is twofold:

1. What use cases is `StablePointer` intended to satisfy?
2. How can we reason about the equality of `StablePointer`. I know that it gives false negatives, but under what circumstances can I expect these to always occur?

Thanks for any insights. They are much appreciated.

-- EDIT --

I discovered that if I build it with `ghc` instead of `runhaskell`, then Example 2 actually does show that they are equal. Example 1 still fails. The question still stands.

Comment: Did you try to use `==` instead of `eqStableName`?

Comment: I just tried and it makes no difference. I hadn't even noticed that `StablePointer a` had an `Eq` instance, but now that you've pointed that out, I see that using `==` does seem more appropriate for my case, since I am doing equality checks on things of the same type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason those return `False` is probably laziness. In GHC, `m` and `n` will refer to different thunks, since they are not evaluated yet. `makeStableName` does not force the value. If you manually force the thunk, they will be the same:

```
  let m = Wrapper myFunc
  a <- makeStableName $! getWrapper m
  b <- makeStableName $! getWrapper m
  print (a `eqStableName` b)
```

This prints `True` (The `$!` will force the value returned by `getWrapper` to WHNF).

Note that if you don't use `runhaskell` but instead compile with `-O1`, GHC will actually compile this code such that it prints `True`. From looking at the Core, it seems that what GHC has done is inlining `m` and `getWrapper` so that the code that is run is effectively this:

```
a <- makeStableName myFunc
b <- makeStableName myFunc
```

Which then of course generates the same stable pointer.

So if you want maximum equality, always force your values before making stable pointers to them. There is no guarrante though that if two values are equal that they are assigned equal stable pointers.

If you haven't read it yet, I also recommend reading [Stretching the storage manager](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/weak.ps.gz) which explains the implementation of stable pointers.

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question, and I will definitely be reading the paper this evening.

Comment: For future interested people, page 7 explains the ideas in this answer pretty well.